# Why are my changes to a nested struct in an array being lost outside of the function making the changes?

Tags: go, methods, struct, nested

I'm still in the "wrestling with the language" stage of my Go progress, so forgive me for almost definitely missing something very obvious here.

I'm defining two structs, one containing the other.  I make an array of the outer structs, pass it to a function, which calls a method on each of the inner structs, modifying their contents.  This change is visible within the function, but when adding the outer structs to an array for returning, the outer function can't see the changes.  I've tried throwing pointers in everywhere to little avail - somewhat thankfully, because it looked awful.

```
package main

import "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"

type inner struct {
  ints []int
}

func (i *inner) grow() {
  i.ints = append(i.ints, 0)
}

type outer struct {
  inner inner
}

func growOs(os []outer) (out []outer) {
  for _, o := range os {
    o.inner.grow()
    out = append(out, o)
  }
  spew.Dump("----------during")
  spew.Dump(out)
  return
}

func main() {
  os := []outer{
    outer{},
    outer{},
  }
  spew.Dump("----------pre")
  spew.Dump(os)
  growOs(os)
  spew.Dump("----------post")
  spew.Dump(os)
}
```

Comment: Function growOs() reutrns modified slice, but you don't modify the slice which you passed to this function. Try os = growOs(os) in your main()

Comment: Aah dang it, that was exactly it.  My toy example didn't accurately represent my actual code; I'll have to rewrite it, thanks.

Comment: For those interested; in my actual problem, I was iterating over the array with `for _, o := range os`, mutating `o`, which was completely lost outside the loop, as the loop makes copies, not references.  I solved it with `for i := range os { os[i].inner.grow() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
func main() {
    os := []outer{
        outer{},
        outer{},
    }
    spew.Dump("----------pre")
    spew.Dump(os)
    growOs(os)
    spew.Dump("----------post")
    spew.Dump(os)
}
```

to

```
func main() {
    os := []outer{
        outer{},
        outer{},
    }
    spew.Dump("----------pre")
    spew.Dump(os)
    os = growOs(os)
    spew.Dump("----------post")
    spew.Dump(os)
}
```

***NOTICE:*** `os = growOs(os)`

in function

```
func growOs(os []outer) (out []outer) {
  for _, o := range os {
    o.inner.grow()
    out = append(out, o)
  }
  spew.Dump("----------during")
  spew.Dump(out)
  return
}
```

you just return a new slice `out`, you don't modify the input slice `os`,

So in your `main` function, the `os` isn't changed.

Comment: In fact it could be inefficient if  a slice contains large amount of data because `growOs` still creates two redundant objects which allocate, take its place in memory and must be utilized by garbage collector.

Answer (score 3):

The `o` in your loop is a copy, so you either have to:

1. Change your slice to be `[]*outer`.
2. Simply use a pointer to each item and modify the items in place.

Ex:

```
for i := range os {
    o := &os[i]
    o.inner.grow()
    // or just os[i].inner.grow()
}
return os
```

3. just assign use the returned slice: `os = growOs(os)`

Comment: I'm very new to Go, but I'd bet on the fact that in `for i, x := range s {...}` the element `x` is a copy is a source of many misunderstandings. This is clearly stated and a "pay attention" in the docs, but the very fact than you need to pay attention seems suspicious.

Comment: It needs to be explained better in the docs, it's a common source of confusion, same with exported members in structs.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Pointer argument vs value argument](https://play.golang.org/p/VpRrJakCli)

If a function expects pointer argument it will obtain a pointer to an object thereby each change executed upon the object will have effect on the object itself. If a function expects a value argument it will obtain a copy of an object so each operation will affect an obtained copy not the object.

```
func recPointer(s *string) {
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", s) // The same object
}

func recValue(s string) {
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &s) // A new object
}

func main() {
    s := "asdf"
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &s)
    recPointer(&s)
    recValue(s)
}
```

#### [Named return values](https://play.golang.org/p/gS3EZY2tXQ)

> Go's return values may be named. If so, they are treated as variables defined at the top of the function.

Thereby it becomes clear that named return values are defined in function not in a name space above it. So when you return a named value you do it with a new object (again).

```
func recValue(s []string) (out []string) {
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &s) // A new object
    out = append(out, s...)
    // Again new object. It is not the `s` from `main`
    // and obviously not the `s` var from incoming arguments.
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &out)
    return
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"asdf"}
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &s)
    recValue(s)
}
```

#### [Fixed example](https://play.golang.org/p/RIGjDSQCV0)

*Be careful! I replaced `spew.Dump` with `fmt.Printf` for demonstrative debug.*

```
// No named return values
// Pointer argument receiver
func growOs(os *[]outer) *[]outer {
    for _, o := range *os {
        o.inner.grow()
        *os = append(*os, o)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%p: %+v \n", os, os)
    return os
}

func main() {
    // `os` is a pointer to the object
    os := &[]outer{
        outer{},
        outer{},
    }
    fmt.Printf("%p: %+v \n", os, os)
    growOs(os)
    fmt.Printf("%p: %+v \n", os, os)
}
```